# Reflexes & Pathologies including the Vagus Nerve

Tags: neurology, cranial-nerves

I only know the vasovagal reflex. I would really appreciate if someone could inform me about the other ones.

About the pathologies, I already know the effects of direct nerve damage. I am talking about more sparse and indirect ones, for example so far I found Roemheld syndrome, which is a gastrocardiac syndrome.

Actually, any subtle clinical presentation including the vagus nerve could be really helpful!

Answer (score 2):

One pathology affecting the vagus nerve is autonomic neuropathy which can be secondary to several causes-one of the most commonly acquired cause is diabetes mellitus. It can manifest with various symptoms such as resting tachycardia (heart beating fast without exercise), exercise intolerance, orthostatic hypotension, constipation, gastroparesis (delayed gastric emptying), etc.

If you'd like to read more-http://care.diabetesjournals.org/content/26/5/1553.full

Hope its helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I know the vagus nerve is linked to ulcerative colitis, which could have serious effects on the brain due to body-wide inflammation. You could probably search "vagus nerve" "colitis" and "neuroinflammation" and get some good papers on pubmed.